# Visual basic: My calendar search only searches the 1st month of the year not the actual month

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an application that reads from a list in a csv file with random dates and years. Then the application should make a calendar for that random list of files.

For example if there is a random month and year in a file that is written "Sep, 2005", the application is September 2005 should display a calendar for the month and year. It does that for every single random month and year in the file. It should also account for leap years, however it already does that already.

My application reads the files. However, it only displays the first month of the year, not the specified month. For example, if I run the app and scroll to Sep 2005, it would give me a calendar of January 2005 instead of September 2005.

I need a way for the app to display the specified month and not the first month of the year.

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

    Dim strSplit(1) As String
    Dim strRecord As String
    Dim fsrFile As New StreamReader("MonthData.csv")
    Dim intCalendar(5, 6) As Integer
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim intStart As Integer = 0

    Dim strWeek() As String = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"}
    Dim intYear As Integer
    Dim strMonth() As String = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}
    Dim intMonth() As Integer = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}

    Dim store As Integer
    Dim intFirstDayOfYear As Integer
    Dim intDayCount As Integer

    Do
        strRecord = fsrFile.ReadLine()
        strSplit = Split(strRecord, ",")
        intYear = CInt(strSplit(1))
        intCounter = 0

        Console.WriteLine(strRecord)

        For intIndex = 0 To 11
            If strSplit(0) = (strMonth(intIndex)) Then
                store = intIndex
            End If
        Next

        For intIndex = 0 To store
            intFirstDayOfYear = CInt((Int((intYear - 1901) * (365.25) + 2.0) Mod 7)) 'This calculates the first day of the year and is important in display 'January
        Next

        For intRow = 0 To intCalendar.GetUpperBound(0)
            For intCol = 0 To intCalendar.GetUpperBound(1)
                If intRow = 0 Then
                    If intCol = intFirstDayOfYear Then
                        intCounter = 1
                    End If
                End If

                intCalendar(intRow, intCol) = intCounter

                If intCounter > 0 Then
                    intCounter += 1
                End If

                If intCounter > intMonth(store) Then
                    intCounter = 0
                End If

                If intYear Mod 4 = 0 And intCounter > 29 Then 
                    intCounter = 0
                ElseIf intYear Mod 4 = 1 And intCounter > intMonth(store)Then
                    intCounter = 0
'These if else statements calculates the leap year and helps account for it
                End If

            Next
        Next

        For intIndex = 0 To strWeek.GetUpperBound(0)
            Console.Write("{0,4:#}", strWeek(intIndex))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine()

        For intRow = 0 To intCalendar.GetUpperBound(0)
            For intCol = 0 To intCalendar.GetUpperBound(1)
                Console.Write("{0,4:#}", intCalendar(intRow, intCol))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

    Loop Until fsrFile.EndOfStream
End Sub
```

Here is one of the months from the ran/output that I copy and pasted. Im posting it to help demonstrate what I said.

```
 Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat

                            1

    2   3   4   5   6   7   8

    9  10  11  12  13  14  15

    16  17  18  19  20  21  22

    23  24  25  26  27  28  29

    30
```

As you can see, the calendar starts at the wrong day because it is displaying the month of january not september
Sep,2005

Here is the months and years that it is reading from:

```
Apr,2054
Aug,2058
Apr,1919
Dec,2027
Jul,2049
Feb,1956
Oct,1953
Jan,1983
May,1977
Nov,2081
Sep,2056
Jan,1996
Nov,2029
Feb,1936
Dec,1995
Sep,2054
Feb,2099
Jul,1930
Mar,1938
Oct,2032
May,2051
May,2092
Dec,2067
Jul,2009
Jun,2039
Dec,2069
Oct,2092
Sep,1905
Feb,2081
Aug,2020
Mar,1991
Mar,2042
May,2085
May,2059
Nov,1929
May,1953
Jun,1938
Feb,2051
Aug,1917
Mar,2054
Jul,1936
Aug,1984
Jun,1914
Jul,1905
Jan,2060
Mar,2062
Oct,1940
Nov,1970
May,1909
Feb,2041
Dec,2068
Jan,2063
Sep,2013
Oct,1999
Nov,1942
Jun,2065
Jan,2062
Mar,1969
Aug,2023
Apr,2048
Nov,2053
Apr,2062
Sep,2038
Sep,1938
Apr,1962
Jun,2007
Aug,2093
Oct,1995
Apr,2002
Jan,1957
Feb,1927
Jun,2052
Jul,1920
Aug,1966
Apr,2093
Jun,1914
Dec,2037
Mar,1926
Jul,2046
Sep,2005
```

Comment: You need to debug your code. Set a breakpoint at the top and step through the code line by line, examining the state at every step. As soon as the state is not what you expect it to be, you have found the issue. You may well be able to diagnose it yourself at that point but, if you can't, at least you can provide us with ALL the relevant information. That includes explaining EXACTLY where the issue occurs, what the code in question is supposed to do and what it actually does. You ALWAYS need to debug your code before posting here and you ALWAYS need to explain the result of that debugging.

Comment: This is nit-picking and I apologize but please get rid of some or all of the blank lines. I get tired of scrolling and it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Can you explain this line `intFirstDayOfYear = CInt(Int((intYear - 1901) * 365.25 + 2.0) Mod 7) 'This calculates the first month of the year` Wouldn't the first month of the year always be January? Why are you assigning the first month of the year to a variable called intFirstDayOfYear? That is confusing code!

Comment: HI, I think we need to understand your intent here. I tried to work out what results you expect and ignoring the code for now, because there are many unclear things in it. You have a file with months and years in. You want to read each line of the file and ... what?  whats the output look like? Looks like setting something in intCalendar, but I cant work out what.

Comment: what my code is doing is it is reading the file and spitting out the calendar of the years for the month and the year. However instead of it giving me the actual month of the year, it would give me the 1st month. For example if I ran the code and looked for september 2005, instead of the calendar displaying the calendar of september 2005, it would display january 2005. That is the problem.

Comment: Whatever your instructor is teaching you about variable prefixes is **WRONG!** This used to be a thing back in the VB6/vbscript era, but with the release VB.Net back in 2001 Microsoft updated their style guidelines to officially recommend **against** annotating variable names this way. They did formal studies to find out it hurts more than it helps.

Comment: As for _why_ the change was made, it used to be common not to use Option Strict or to use more variant types, and the tools weren't as good. In that context, a type descriptor on variable names was helpful and good. Modern code should use Option Strict, and the tooling (Visual Studio) tells you more about the type at each place you use the variable. Modern code also tends to shorter methods, where each use of a variable is closer to the initial declaration. So the type prefix is no longer helpful, and only adds noise to the code. It inhibits, rather than helps, a reader to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't figure out what you desired result was. It appears you are concerned about accounting for leap years and getting the correct number of days in a month. .Net has already included a lot of this functionality in the framework.

I used your file data to demonstrate how your code could be made easier.

```
Private Sub FunWithDates()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\MonthYear.csv")
    Dim lst As New List(Of Date)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim splits = line.Split(","c)
        Dim MonthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(splits(0), "MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
        Dim d As New Date(CInt(splits(1)), MonthNumber, 1)
        lst.Add(d)
    Next
    lst.Sort()
    For Each d In lst
        'This will print an ordered list of Months Years
        Debug.Print($"{d:MMM yyyy} is a leap year? {Date.IsLeapYear(d.Year)}")
    Next
    'To find the last day of a month
    For Each d In lst
        Dim lastDay = d.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
        Debug.Print($"The last day of {d:MMM yyyy} is {lastDay:MMM dd, yyyy}")
    Next
    'Note that the last day of Feb 1956 is the 29th. Check the results of the first loop
    'and you will see that 1956 is indeed a leap year.
    For Each d In lst
        Debug.Print($"{d:MMM dd, yyyy} is a {d.DayOfWeek}")
    Next
    'Note that when using an interpolated string the format for the date follows the colon
    'and is not enclosed by double quotes.
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Mary, what my code was doing was it was reading the file and spitting out the calendar of the years for the month and the year. However instead of it giving me the actual month of the year, it would give me the 1st month. For example if I ran the code and looked for september 2005, instead of the calendar displaying the calendar of september 2005, it would display january 2005. That is my issue. The leap years and getting the correct amount of days were not really a problem. Also I tried to run your code however it gives me an error for "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture", What does it do?

Comment: `CultrueInfo.CurrentCulture` simply sets various defaults to the current culture. It requires `Imports System.Globalization` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You've made this **WAY** harder than it needs to be.

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim formatString As String = "MMM,yyyy,dd"

    Dim lines = File.ReadLines("MonthData.csv")
    For Each line As String In lines
        PrintCalendar(DateTime.ParseExact(line+",01", formatString, Nothing))
    Next line
End Sub

Public Sub PrintCalendar(firstDayOfMonth As DateTime)
    'Print Month Header
    Console.WriteLine($"{firstDayOfMonth,17:MMM yyyy}")

    'Print Week Header
    Console.WriteLine("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat")
    Console.WriteLine("--- --- --- --- --- --- ---")

    'Blank spaces at start of first week
    Dim startOfWeek As Integer = firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek
    Console.Write(new String(" "c, startOfWeek*4))
                
    'Print each day
    For i As Integer = 1 To DateTime.DaysInMonth(firstDayOfMonth.Year, firstDayOfMonth.Month)
        Console.Write($"{i,3} ")

        'End of week
        If (i + startOfWeek) Mod 7 = 0 Then Console.WriteLine()
    Next

    'Final line break and spacer
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/oin9g1

Comment: Your code does work however the assignment is to be done without imports such as  System.Globalization. So I can not use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. Your code is of some help however so I appreciate it

Comment: @Anonymous Updated to remove use of System.Globalization

Comment: @Anonymous I don't use System.Linq anymore, either.

Comment: I dont need my entire code revamp. The lecturer wants us to use a lot of the things I have in my code. So things like intFirstDayOfYear, intCalendar, strWeek(), strSplit are all very important and are not just random things.

Comment: You should still break this into multiple methods. Separate out the code to find how many days in a month into it's own method